WSO2 has not a bin directory
I want to install WSO2 API manager. The install instructions talk about scripts in a /bin directory, but this directory doesn't exist. I have searched in several pages of documentation and I still didn't find out what I am doing wroing.

I download the release (I tried two, 2.6 and 4.1), in .zip and tar.gz format.
I uncompress the release file
I stop because there is no /bin directory inside the product-apim folder.

In fact, the /bin folder doesn't exist in the Github repository.
I see that all README keeps a initial step like this:
"Extract the wso2am-4.4.0.zip and go to the 'bin' directory" (https://github.com/wso2/product-apim#installation--running)
Well, where is the bin directory, or better, how can I get it?

The /bin directory is in the compiled product, which you can download from releases: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v4.3.0
In the source code, there is no /bin directory.

Thank you very much, @tmoasz. More a doubt: Do you know if there is a rule for the compiled product is available for some releases and not for the other ones? For example, there is a compiled file for v2.0.0, but there are no files for v2.6.0 and v3.0.0. If there is a documentation about this rule, I thank you very much. I have a legacy with WSO2 2.6.0 and I am trying to reproduce the deployment.

Well, i don't why there is no release zip file.. Maybe you should write to WSO2 support. Maybe they will kindly share with you, compiled apim-2.6.0, Otherwise You can build from source - it is also possible.
